# displayModeButtonItem is disappearing when I collapse/expand screen

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

So my use-case is that I have a `TabBarController` in the detailview, and around four tabs each with its own `NavigationController`. All are via storyboard. Then on my `App Delegate` I have this:

```
let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
let tabBarController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UITabBarController
for item in tabBarController.viewControllers!{
        let navigationController = item as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem
}
```

And so I have a `Button` on each `NavigationController`. The issue is at first when I use the button on the first tab, it works fine, but as soon as I move tabs, when I return to the previous tabs and use the button, it disappears. Then, when I switch to another tab, it goes back. Surprisingly, this doesn't happen on the last tab. I've tried to search for a solution but I can't find any. And so I'm in a slump right now.

I added a gif to show the behavior.

[image]

EDIT: I don't know if this matters, but this project is landscape-only.

Comment: Without a clear look on the code this cant be explained, maybe the leftBarButton item is being set nil at some point or anything.

Comment: A previous answerer uploaded his project on this path: https://github.com/lukaswuerzburger/display-mode-switcher/
I don't know what happened to his answer, but the same thing happens to this sample.

Comment: when i used your code in the project uploaded it seems to work fine for me and not like the behaviour of the gif above.

Comment: I see. I'll give it another go. Just in case, did you try it in landscape mode or portrait mode? I've tested that source in both simulator and device, and it's still happening in my environment.

Comment: Landscape mode, Yeah use the project which you uploaded here and try to use your code in that and see whether you to get the behaviour as told.

Comment: I'm still getting the behavior I described. It starts to happen when you get to the last tab. After that return to the first, second and third tab and try to use the displayModeButtonItem. My current workaround is to just remove the expand button from the other tabs, since we need it only on the first tab, but I still want to know why this is happening, and eventually put it back once  a workaround is found. I currently used one of my DTS support tickets just for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a UIKit bug. Behavior actually depends on the order of view controllers, on which you set `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`. The bug will start reproducing after view of the last one of them will be loaded.

There is a hacky workaround though. Add this to the object, which implements `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` of your `UISplitViewController`

```
func splitViewController(_ svc: UISplitViewController, willChangeTo displayMode: UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let tabBarController = svc.viewControllers.last as! UITabBarController
        let navigationController = tabBarController.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.viewControllers.first?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        navigationController.viewControllers.first?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = svc.displayModeButtonItem
    }
}
```

It will work without `DispatchQueue.main.async`, but `leftBarButtonItem`'s position would be wrong for some reason, and I don't know a way to update it's layout.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks. It's indeed a hacky workaround, but I get the idea. 
Still waiting from official response from Apple since I already filed the ticket.

Comment: Apples response is in the other answer, make sure it is only on the visible controller and problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add an answer as an additional information per the official support from Apple, in case anyone wonders:

"UISplitViewController’s displayModeButtonItem can only reside in one place in the view hierarchy at a time, not in multiple places or multiple view controllers. Currently you are pointing it to all the view controllers in the tabbar.
Doing so yields unpredictable results as we have seen."

The accepted answer, though quite a hacky workaround, works. Apple's support recommendation though, is work on it in the TabBarController level.

Comment: Thanks I instead added it in viewWillAppear and removed it in viewDidDissapear and fixed my problem